1960's movie with a killer vacuum cleaner?
I'm trying to find a horror movie that had a killer vacuum cleaner and was made in the 1960's.
Here's what I remember:

It was a live action horror movie.
Saw a preview in a drive-in circa 1968-ish.  Never saw the movie itself.
The preview featured the standard "woman screaming and being chased" stuff.
The preview was sufficient to give my sister (about 3-5 at the time) nightmares. I'd love to be able to give her a DVD or poster for her birthday. :)
We vaguely remember that it was a canister vacuum; but not sure since this pic reminded sis of it:

and that's an upright.


I was about to ask a very similar question - but it was about all sorts of appliances (among them, a TV) which were attacking people. I saw it in the early 70' so this must be a different movie.

@WoJ, I can't be sure that it was just a vacuum in the movie.  That's just the part I remember from the preview.

Are we sure about the time period? Over-sexed Rugsuckers from Mars woudl seem to fit but it's 1989.

@Paulie_D, reasonably sure.  I saw it in 1968-ish, it was in color and not made before the 1950's from what I remember of the styles (generic 50's/60's). Probahbly made in the mid 1960s, But we can tack on +/- 5 years to account for my growing Alzheimer's. ;) ... Also, I definitely would've remembered a title like Over-sexed Rugsuckers from Mars!

@BrockAdams: unfortunately it does not, Benny Hill was not existant at the time (or at least not broadcast) and it was a real movie.

Was it It Crawled Out of the Woodwork?

@John, I don't think so.  We remember more chasing and screaming.  Good find though.  If you've got a date for that, then it might narrow down the movie date (you know how somebody gets an idea and then movies and TV shows all come out about the same time, trying to exploit that idea).  ETA:  Apparently that was from a TV episode that first aired on December 9th, 1963 -- a few years before the movie ad we saw.

This sounds a lot like the Benny Hill Show sketch called The Appliance Revolt.  Someone gets wrapped up by a phone cord, a washer or dryer eats someone, I think I remember a vacuum chasing a person, and TV's and other appliances marching down the street.  Episode 38 of the series.  It may have even been done in a trailer format, but I'll have to hunt down a copy to know for sure.
eta - This reddit post is where I got the episode number.
https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/1n4v61/tomt_nightmare_fuel_clip_of_what_appears_to_be/
I definitely remember the shot from the imgur link there:
http://i.imgur.com/9FERNti.gif

If it was a vacuum cleaner, and a Benny Hill sketch, then it was probably chasing a woman and eventually pulled off her dress.

Several things don't fit: (1) That clip is animated, the preview was live-action. (2) We saw this at a drive-in.  Previews for TV shows were never shown at movie theaters (¿until the 2000's? Are they shown now?). (3) We didn't even have a TV at the time. (4) The Benny Hill show didn't start appearing in the USA until the late 70s -- about a decade after what we saw (and later still for "heartland" areas of the USA).

Fair enough.  However, that clip IS live-action.  It's cardboard, other physical props, and creative lighting.
